# How to enable Seekbar on touch event if it is already disabled, through code in android?

Tags: android, seekbar

I'm making a code in which i set seekbar disabled when it attains some particular position and after disabled it should get enabled if user touched it again. for that i used onTouch Listener. But it didn't enabled once get disabled, here is the code

```
seek.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            seek.setEnabled(true);

            return false;
        }
    });


seek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {

            if (progress > 23 ) {
                seek.setEnabled(false);
            } 
        }
    });
```

Thanks in advance. Please Help

Comment: If you set  seek.setEnabled(false); then it doesn't accept any listeners.

Comment: then how can i make this happen, i just want that my seekbar should not move after 23 value and should move below 23 only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of my knowledge it is not possible but you can set progress up to 23 only

how much user will scroll it will set at 23 only.

In OnSeekBarChangeListener

```
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
            boolean fromUser) {

        if (progress > 23 ) {
            seek.setProgress(23);
        } 
    }
```

Hope this will helps you.